# Doctrine - ManytoMany Filter Result

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to get a filter result from a many to many relationship in doctrine.

```
Class Users extends RecordItem {
    /**
    * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
    * @var int
    **/

    protected $id;
     /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company")
     * @JoinTable(name="users_join_company",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $companys;

    /**
    * @Column(type="string", length=100)
    * @var string
    */
    protected $username;   
    //edit - > added array collection - forgotten
    public function __construct() {
        $this->companys = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

Class Company extends Recorditem {

    /**
    * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
    * @var int
    **/
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @Column(type="string", length=100)
    * @var string
    */
    protected $company_name;  
}
```

so far I'm only able to query all company from the following code, is there a proper way to add a filter? example: there are 3 company in array collection, would want to return one with specify company "id"

```
$user = $entityManager->getRepository('Users')->findOneBy(['id'=>1]);

$companys = $user->companys; // hope to return only company with the id 1

foreach($companys as $company){
    echo $company->company_name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter a collection, use ArrayCollection ...

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

Example :

```
// I guess companies is an ArrayCollection
$myDesiredCompanies = $companies->filter(function (Company $entry) {
    return ($entry->getId() == 1);
});
```

It will filter the collection and return a new Collection with your desired results

Comment: Yes you are right it is an ArrayCollection accidentally removed the construct while trying to simplify the code. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that companies are lazy loaded and not affected by any kind of restriction. `$user->getCompanies()` will always return all companies regardless.

You need to a) use the QueryBuilder and b) hydrate your entities from your filtered result set.

E.g.

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$users = $qb->select('u', 'c') // important - select all entities in query to avoid lazy loading which ignores query constraints
  ->from('YourBundle:Users', 'u')
  ->join('u.companys', 'c')
  ->where('u.id = :userId')
  ->andWhere('c.id = :companyId')
  ->setParameter('userId', 1)
  ->setParameter('companyId', 1)
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult();
```

This will get you all users with id 1 (so one user) and will only fetch companies with id matching 1.

If you wanted you could use getOneOrNullResult() instead of getResult to fetch a single user.

Answer (score 0):

with a query builder you can use something like this:

```
$s_program = $qb->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();
```

In your case try this substitute:

```
$user = $entityManager->getRepository('Users')->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();
```

I don't know if it will work, but try it out!

Comment: tested and error return "The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy", but kinda understand what is the intention . will try to work around this.